# Como saber se o objeto passado é um elemento DOM?

Tags: javascript, validação, dom

Estou trabalhando com funções na qual eu devo passar (**Obrigatoriamente**) um elemento DOM.
Esta função ira trabalhar com as propriedades deste elemento DOM.

#### Exemplo

```js
function changeValue(elem, value){
  elem.value = value;
}

var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
changeValue(input, input.value.toUpperCase());
```

```html
<input name="name" value="Guilherme" />
```

#### Duvida

- Como verificar se o elemento é realmente um elemento DOM?
  e não uma instancia do `jQuery` ou `{ value : 'Guilherme'}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função abaixo, retirei dessa [resposta.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/384380/5314295)

```js
function isElement(o) {
  return (
    typeof HTMLElement === "object" ? o instanceof HTMLElement : //DOM2
    o && typeof o === "object" && o !== null && o.nodeType === 1 && typeof o.nodeName === "string"
  );
}

console.log(isElement(document.getElementById("campo"))); // elemento
console.log(isElement($("#campo"))); // objeto jQuery
console.log(isElement($("#campo")[0])); // elemento
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="campo">
```

Comment: Tem uma atualização. 
"The previous code didn't work in Chrome because Node and HTMLElement are functions instead of the expected object."

Comment: Bem observado! Alterei adicionando a versão atual. =)